# What's the first noticeable instance of Hermione showing the negative effects due to her timeturner use in the third year?

Tags: harry-potter, time-travel, hermione-granger

We know that through the entire year Hermione is using the time turner to attend multiple classes at the same time.

Do we have a definitive moment when we can see the effects of this impacting her negatively?

Comment: I've never understood why she didn't just use the time turner to take a nap...

Comment: @Jack lol right, i always assumed mcgonagall told her to ONLY use it to go to class, and so Hermione did just that, instead of doubling up her sleep, and study time as well as class time.

Comment: This feels very subjective....

Comment: @Jack: Maybe she did. But as MiB tells us, if you work 36 hour days, you'll either get used to it, or have a psychotic episode.

Comment: @Jack There might be restrictions on the usage of Time Turner like 4hrs max.

Answer (score 33):

The start of the second term seems to be when the increased workload (and lack of sleep) begins to take its toll.

> *Even so, he wasn’t showing the strain nearly as much as Hermione,
> whose immense workload finally seemed to be getting to her. Every
> night, without fail, Hermione was to be seen in a corner of the common
> room, several tables spread with books, Arithmancy charts, Rune
> dictionaries, diagrams of Muggles lifting heavy objects, and file upon
> file of extensive notes; **she barely spoke to anybody, and snapped when
> she was interrupted.***
>
> <sub><sup>HP: PoA (CHAPTER TWELVE – The Patronus)</sup></sub>

Comment: I was right behind you. Yeah, I think so, too. I can't find or think of anything as good as that that comes earlier, but it'll be hard to prove there isn't anything :P

Comment: _diagrams of Muggles lifting heavy objects_ I wonder what that is about?

Comment: @TaW - Muggle studies. Since they can't use magic, obvs

Answer (score 6):

"Negative effects" is somewhat relative. One could argue that having to ignore your friends because you are not allowed to tell them the truth is a slightly negative thing, so the first instance would be

> “Well, I’m taking more new subjects than you, aren’t I,” said
>   Hermione. “Those are my books for Arithmancy, Care of Magical
>   Creatures, Divination, the Study of Ancient Runes, Muggle Studies —”
>
> “What are you doing Muggle Studies for?” said Ron, rolling his eyes at
>   Harry. “You’re Muggle-born! Your mum and dad are Muggles! You already
>   know all about Muggles!”
>
> “But it’ll be fascinating to study them from the wizarding point of
>   view,” said Hermione earnestly.
>
> “Are you planning to eat or sleep at all this year, Hermione?” asked
>   Harry, while Ron sniggered. **Hermione ignored them.**
>
> <sub>— *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*, Chapter four (The Leaky Cauldron)</sub>